# scala implicit method argument eliminate ambiguity

Tags: scala, implicit

I don't quite understand following code:

```
object M {
   implicit object AMarker
   implicit object BMarker

   def m(ints: Seq[Int])(implicit i: AMarker.type ): Unit = {
     println(s"int seq $ints");
   }

   def m(strs: Seq[String])(implicit s: BMarker.type ): Unit = {
     println(s"string seq $strs")
   }
 }

 import M._

 m(Seq(1, 2, 3))
 m(Seq("a", "b", "c"))
```

If it weren't for the two markers, it will not compile because the two `m` methods have the same signature after type erasure.

However, I don't understand what is the "magic" that links `AMarker` to a `Seq[Int]`, and `BMarker` to `Seq[String]`.

More specificly, when I call `m(Seq("a", "b"))`, how does the compiler know it should use the implicit `BMarker`, and call the second `m`?  Hasn't the `Seq` already been type erased?

Comment: Because the type information of Seq[A] is available at compile time to call the correct method, but that information isn't available at runtime

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but an interesting observation: you can also eliminate ambiguity by making one `m()` a function and leaving the other as a method. No implicits or markers needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question directly, no, the type erasure hasn't happened yet. Implicit search has to happen with full knowledge of types. To see how these methods look at runtime, you can run `javap` to see the compiled classes:

```
scala> :javap M -s
Compiled from "<console>"
public class M$ {
  public static final M$ MODULE$;
    Signature: LM$;
  public static {};
    Signature: ()V

  public void m(scala.collection.Seq<java.lang.Object>, M$AMarker$);
    Signature: (Lscala/collection/Seq;LM$AMarker$;)V

  public void m(scala.collection.Seq<java.lang.String>, M$BMarker$);
    Signature: (Lscala/collection/Seq;LM$BMarker$;)V

  public M$();
    Signature: ()V
}
```

So basically the compiler has made unambiguous runtime methods. It looks up the exact method during compile time, and essentially uses the implicit object to disambiguate.

Cool trick BTW! I haven't seen it used directly this way before.